# Entity Core Exception: must be reducible node

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm getting an exception in Entity Core 1.1.0 when I try to "concatenate" multiple IQueryable where clauses that use a Navigation Property.

Simple example (not my actual code):

```
var testUsers = _context.Users.AsNoTracking().Include(a => a.Company)
            .Where(a => a.Company != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Company.Name) && a.Company.Name.Contains("E"));

testUsers = testUsers
            .Where(a => a.Company != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Company.Name) && a.Company.Name.Contains("D"));

testUsers.ToList(); //Exception Message: must be reducible node
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceAndCheck()
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceExtensions()
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExtensionExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
....
```

Seems like a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Apparently bug (as usual for EF Core).